# How to draw a line over any shape in threejs?

Tags: three.js, geometry, line, shapes, vertices

let's say i have a geometric shape (could be of any shape) or glb model, what i'm trying a achieve is to draw a line over that shape

what i tried is, got the vertices for the line geometry manually from the ***BufferGeometry.attribute.position.array***

```
const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1.5,1.5,1.5,2,2,2);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color:0xffffff,
  wireframe:true
});
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry,material);
scene.add(mesh);

const lineGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
const lineGeometryVertices = new Float32Array([
  0,-0,.75,
  .75,-0,.75,
  .75,-0,-0
]);


const lineBufferAttribute = new THREE.BufferAttribute(lineGeometryVertices,3);
lineGeometry.setAttribute("position",lineBufferAttribute);

const lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  color:0xff0000,
  linewidth:3
})

const line = new THREE.Line(lineGeometry,lineMaterial);
scene.add(line);
```

[image: I got this as result, which is what i hoping to achieve]

But i got the vertices for the line geometry manually as i said previously, what i want to achieve is

1. ***How to draw a line over any shape (the shape could be regular shape like cube or sphere or it could be a irregular shape like a terrain)?***

I think figuring out how to get the vertices  for the line geometry that needs to go over the geometric shape is the key or it could be done some other.

***The problem here is that drawing a line geometry over any shape is pretty ease once you got the vertices, but the hard task is to get the vertices i need for the line geometry, that is what i don't know how to do it.***

I don't know how, please help me solve this issue.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "over"? Does your example there produce the correct result? Could you explain it?

Comment: The red line that is drawn over the cube wireframe, the example produces correct result but that is limited meaning, the vertices for the line geometry is figured out manually (console.log out all the vertices of the cube and take one vertex at a time and insert them in the line geometry. What i want now is that, how to draw a line over any geometric shape

Comment: The wireframe contains a lot of line segments. Here you pick 2 of them. Why those 2?

Comment: I wanted to test whether i can able to draw a line over the cube that why i picked those 2

Comment: Still unclear what you mean with "line over the cube". Can you just pick any two vertices in the mesh and draw a line between them?